# How do I create a relationship between AspNetUserRoles and some other table using EF6 code first?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I'm using ASP.Net Identity 2 and EF6 code first migrations for this project and I'm struggling to create a table to link 3 other tables. I have the following:

- Company
- ApplicationUser (AspNetUsers)
- ApplicationRole (AspNetRoles)
- AspNetUserRoles

The tricky bit is to relate the AspNetUserRoles with the Company table, because a user can have roles in different companies and can also have a role that's not related to any company. So ideally the resulting table I need would be something like:

- CompanyUserRoles(companyId, UserRoleId[this is not roleID]) or even (companyId, roleid,userid)

Another option would be to add another field (companyId) to the AspNetUserRoles table.

It's kind of confusing how can I achieve this with code first and what implications would it have when it comes to the UserManager and RoleManager (do I need to create custom ones?).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the same source code and write the code yourself walking assumptions now.
First, you create new project in vs with mvc(c#) and select project type on mvc.
Then, after create project you should change some classes Identity.
I want change to type `UserId` that has been `Nvarchar(128)` to `Bigint` in table `AspNetUsers`.
Step one to seven are in `IdentityModels.cs`.

step one: you change class `IdentityModels.cs` to according to the:

```
ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

change to : `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>`.

Step two: create classes:

```
public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<long> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<long> { }
```

step three:
change class according to the :

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, long> manager)
```

Step four: change class according to the :

```
 public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<long, CustomUserRole>
```

Step five:  change class according to the :

```
 public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
```

Step six: change class according to the :

```
public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, long, CustomUserRole>
```

Step seven: change class according to the :

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
```

and add method below to `IdentityModels.cs` according your table field:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
        //.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId })
        //.ToTable("tblRoles");

        //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
        //    .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
        //    .ToTable("tblMembers");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasKey(r => new { r.Id }).ToTable("tblMembers1").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(r => new { r.Id }).ToTable("tblMembers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId }).ToTable("tblRoless");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(r => new { r.UserId }).ToTable("tblLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().HasKey(r => new { r.Id }).ToTable("tblUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.Id }).ToTable("tblRoloess");
    }
```

In `AccountControllers.cs` change according to the :

```
 private bool HasPassword()
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId<long>());

        if (user != null)
        {
            return user.PasswordHash != null;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public virtual ActionResult RemoveAccountList()
    {
        var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId<long>());
        ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
        return PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
    }
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
    {
        ManageMessageId ? message = null;
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(
            User.Identity.GetUserId<long>(),
            new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<long>());
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            message = ManageMessageId.Error;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
        { IsPersistent = isPersistent },
                                        await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
    }
```

And `IdentityConfig.cs` change according to the :

```
  public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

// Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, long>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, long> store) : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
         new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, long>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords 
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone 
        // and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user 
        // You can write your own provider and plug in here. 
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode",
            new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, long>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
            });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode",
            new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, long>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
            });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, long>(
                    dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
}

public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, long>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Then, in windows **Package Manager Console** in Tools menu write commands below for add migration :

```
Enable migrations
```

Then :

```
Add-migration TestMig
```

According the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA67W.jpg)

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't reply to my question.

Comment: You want change fied UserId to companyId: step 1 to 7 .

Comment: You want change your table name : IdentityModels.cs

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I don't want to change userId to companyId anywhere and don't want to change table names either.